# How do i truncate url using Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

How do i truncate the below URL next to the domain "com" using Hive script. i.e you tube.com only

```
    http://www.youtube.com/video/AiL6nL
    http://www.yahoo.com/video/Hhj9B2
    http://www.youtube.com/video/MpVHQ
    http://www.google.com/video/PGuTN
    http://www.youtube.com/video/VU34MI
```

s it possible to truncate like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a case statement:

```
CASE WHEN parse_url((url), 'HOST') is NULL THEN url ELSE parse_url((url), 'HOST') END as parsed_url
```

Answer (score 3):

try

`select split(url, '/')[0] from mytable`

where `mytable` is your table and `url` is the column containing data sampled in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest usage of Hive UDF:

parse_url(string urlString, string partToExtract [, string keyToExtract])

Returns the specified part from the URL. Valid values for partToExtract include HOST, PATH, QUERY, REF, PROTOCOL, AUTHORITY, FILE, and USERINFO. e.g.

parse_url('http://facebook.com/path1/p.php?k1=v1&k2=v2#Ref1', 'HOST') returns 'facebook.com'. Also a value of a particular key in QUERY can be extracted by providing the key as the third argument, e.g. parse_url('http://facebook.com/path1/p.php?k1=v1&k2=v2#Ref1', 'QUERY', 'k1') returns 'v1'.

Thanks,
Dino

Answer (score 0):

To handle both "youtube.com/video/nvRuX9h2" and "probuilds.net" :

```
select split(concat(url,'/'), '/')[0] from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

select parse_url_tuple(column_name,'HOST') from table_name